# loading screen on jquery ajax call is not coming

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show a show a loading screen when a ajax call is made and hide loading screen when ajax call gets complete. I have written the code for it but it works only in mozilla. I want it to work in all browsers.
My HTML code is like-

```
<div id="loadScreen" style="display: none;width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0pt;left: 0pt;">
   <div id="loadScr" style="filter: alpha(opacity = 65);  z-index: 9999;border: medium none; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0pt;left: 0pt; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.2; cursor: wait; position: fixed;"></div>
   <div id="loader"  style="z-index: 10000; position: fixed; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;width: 30%; top: 40%; left: 35%; text-align: center;cursor: wait; ">
     <img src="IMG/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery coding is-

```
$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function () {
     $('#loadScreen').show();
   },
   type: "POST",
   async: false,
   url: serviceUrl,
   data: jsonData,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   complete:function(){
     $('#loadScreen').hide();
   },
   success: function (result) {
     ProcessAjaxResponse(result);
   },
   error: function (errorMsg) {
     //TODO:Lets see
   }
});
```

Comment: What does your showLoadingScreen function look like?  What are the z-index props for loadScreen and its container?

Comment: there is no method like showLoadingScreen. All i am doing is $('#loadScreen').show(); and $('#loadScreen').hide(); All css properties are applied in the html itself

Comment: I tested the code that you have provided in IE7-9, Chrome, and FF.  It works in all three.  Do you have a more comprehensive test page?

Comment: if you have commented out the $('#loadScreen').hide();  then you will be able to see the loading screen in all browsers but my problem is that as soon as a Ajax call is made, i want the loading screen to come. This happens only in FF. In other browsers it doesn't come at all though the browser hangs until the success call back or error call back is called.

Answer (score 1):

Show your screen before the ajax call and place the ajax call in the 'show' callback.  This will ensure the screen is updated right before the ajax call is made.

```
$('#loadScreen').show(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //now happens above
        },
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function() {
            $('#loadScreen').hide();
        },
        success: function(result) {
            ProcessAjaxResponse(result);
        },
        error: function(errorMsg) {
            //TODO:Lets see
        }
    });
});
```